# TensorFlow Custom Allocator and Accessing Data from Tensor

Tags: c++, c, struct, tensorflow

In TensorFlow, you can create custom allocators for various reasons (I am doing it for new hardware). Due to the structure of the device, I need to use a struct of a few elements as my data pointer which the allocator returns as a `void*`.

In the kernels that I am writing, I am given access to Tensors but I need t get the pointer struct that I wrote. Examining the classes, it seemed that I could get this struct by doing `tensor_t.buf_->data()`

[`Tensor::buf_`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h#L430)

[`TensorBuffer::data()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h#L475)

The problem is that I can't find code that does this and I am worried that it is unsafe (highly likely!) or there is a more standard way to do this.

Can someone confirm if this is a good/bad idea? And provide an alternative if such exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also be able to use [Tensor::tensor_data()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h#L405).data() to get access to the raw pointer, without using the weird indirection through DMAHelper.

Comment: How can I construct a Tensor from raw pointer? And when should I delete the raw pointer? THX.

Answer (score 0):

Four days later ...

```
void* GetBase(const Tensor* src) {
  return const_cast<void*>(DMAHelper::base(src));
}
```

from [GPUUtils](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_util.cc#L111)

[`DMAHelper::base()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/dma_helper.h#L27) is a friend class method that is given the ability to use the private [`Tensor::base()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h#L459) to get at the data pointer.

The [implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h#L493) shows that this is all just a wrapper around what I wanted to do after yet another [abstraction](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h#L487). I am guessing it is a safer approach to getting the pointer and should be used instead.