# TensorFlow Casting Internal Tensor Pointer

Tags: c++, templates, macros, tensorflow

I [previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39797095/tensorflow-custom-allocator-and-accessing-data-from-tensor) how to get at the pointer within a Tensor. I would now like to figure out the datatype is stored and then be able to cast `void*`'s to this data type.

Tensor's have a function,

`DataType dtype() const { return shape_.data_type(); }`

`DataType` is a simple enum and doesn't actually help me cast. I would like to be able `static_cast<type>` things to the result of `dtype()`. So I am looking for a macro or template that can do this for me.

Does such exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework is build in [`types.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/types.h#L142) and is used in [`queue_base.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc#L31)

Unfortunately, because it is a template, you need to use macros and such so that each different template gets compiled.

First write function that gets the type as a template parameter

```
template <DataType DT>
Status HandleSliceToElement(const Tensor& parent, Tensor* element,
                            int64 index) {
  typedef typename EnumToDataType<DT>::Type T;
  ...
}
```

Then use macros to handle each datatype. Trimmed for brevity (See full [list of macros](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc#L361))

```
Status QueueBase::CopySliceToElement(const Tensor& parent, Tensor* element,
                                     int64 index) {
#define HANDLE_TYPE(DT)                                                   \
  if (parent.dtype() == DT) {                                             \
    TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(HandleSliceToElement<DT>(parent, element, index)); \
    return Status::OK();                                                  \
  }
  HANDLE_TYPE(DT_FLOAT);
  HANDLE_TYPE(DT_HALF);
  HANDLE_TYPE(DT_DOUBLE);
  ...
#undef HANDLE_TYPE
  return errors::Unimplemented("CopySliceToElement Unhandled data type: ",
                               parent.dtype());
}
```